# Joomla 4 Development

Tags: joomla

I am running Joomla 4 on a test site and am running into several issues. I am not a developer, however, I would like to assist in the development of Joomla 4 and Civicrm. As I come across issues, what is the best way to report them and assist in moving forward?

Answer (score 0):

If it's something where you're not sure if it's a bug or how it's supposed to work, then searching here and then posting a question in stackexchange is good. If you think it's a bug and it's specific to joomla you can check if it's already listed at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues and post issues there.

Non-joomla specific questions work the same way, just if posting an issue at lab.civicrm.org you'd use an appropriate group (usually Core): https://lab.civicrm.org/dev

There is also a joomla channel at https://chat.civicrm.org for chat.

Comment: Thank You Demerit. Some of the issues have been reported there. What I'm seeing, I'm certain are bugs or parts entirely missing. I'll post to the Joomla specific one as these are specific to Joomla 4. I want to do my part to help out but do not have development experience that would be useful.

Comment: Even if you can just do testing when somebody posts a fix that's always helpful.